# QGIS - How can I convert a raster file to a vector file without making same value cells into one polygon?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon

How can I convert a raster file to a vector file without making same value cells into one polygon?

[image]
In the attached image, the values "2124", "2269", "2321", "2634", and "2920" are the polygons automatically combined. Is there any way to convert each pixel to one polygon?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. This appears to be two different questions, and the Q&A format of this site works best with only one question per Question. I'd recommend that you concentrate on one of them and research the other one separately, alternatively post as a separate question.

Comment: Are you sure that you need this ? Cell based analysis will be more efficient in the raster format.

Comment: Hi radouxju, thanks for your comment. I'd like to display cells' values. I couldn't find any option for raster files to display them but for polygons as labels, that's why I need to convert.

Comment: @user26767 You should specify what tool you used to create the undesired above result. I assume you used the GDAL polygonize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a fishnet with the [Vector grid](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_ftools.html) tool in the Vector->Research Tools menu.
2. Assign raster values to the polygons with the "Add grid values to shapes" tool in the Processing Toolbox (Simplified interface, GeoAlgorithms, Raster-vector, Raster->vector operations).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Luke. I was able to get the result which I exactly wanted. And now I know the there is such toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Another very good solution out there is to use the native QGIS Toolbox--> Vector Creation--> Raster pixels to polygons. As of QGIS 3.24, this algorithm still splits each cell into a separate polygon, unlike the GDal polygonize (Raster to Vector) function which I assume you used.

Depending on what you were trying to do, either function could be useful since I ironically was directed to this post when trying to research how to get like cells to cluster together. Also see this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340284/converting-raster-pixels-to-polygons-with-gdal-python) for visuals.

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one.